# jquery select2 prepopulation not working: the field is empty

Tags: jquery, tags, jquery-select2, populate

Just can't get the select2 to pre populate the tags field. The code is quite simple

```
$.getJSON('http://pblog/tags/show/' + post, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#tags').select2({
          data: data,
          placeholder: 'choose your tags',
          tags: true,
        });
      });
```

The url returns this:

```
[{"result":46,"text":"Food"},{"result":48,"text":"Travel"}]
```

yet the field stays empty. As I read the initSelection was removed, so I don't really know what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I edded up creating a little api interface, to retrieve the needed tags.
The code for that looks like this:

```
  $.getJSON('http://pblog/tags/show/' + post, function(data) {
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
          var item = data[d];

          // Create the DOM option that is pre-selected by default
          var option = new Option(item.text, item.text, true, true);

          // Append it to the select
          $('#tags').append(option);
        }
        $('#tags').trigger('change');
      });
```

The url at the first line is the api adress which respons is a json array of the post tags.